# how to run awk from specific line number stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I want to get the line numbers of the first appearance of `bar` after the appearance of `foo`.

This should run in a `while` loop, for the whole file. Like this:

test_file:

```
bar foo
xxx
xxx
xxx
bar
bar
xxx
bar
xxxx
xxx
xx
bar foo
xxx
xxx
bar foo
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
xxx
bar
```

I must find the first `bar` after the `foo`, but NOT in the line with the `foo`. If there are following to `bar foo` I want it to be found. Line 15 isn't found.

It should return:

```
linenumbersfoo: 1 12 15
linenumbersbar: 5 15 21
```

My code:

```
linenumbersfoo=($(awk '/foo/ {print FNR}' test_file.sh))
length="${#linenumbersfoo[@]}"

while [[ $COUNTERR -lt length  ]]; do
number=$((${linenumbersfoo["$COUNTERR"]}))

linenumbersbar[$COUNTERR]=$(awk '"$number"<=NR, /bar/ {print FNR;exit;}' test_file.sh)

let COUNTERR=COUNTERR+1 
done

echo "${linenumbersfoo[@]}"

echo "${linenumbersbar[@]}"
```

I get:

```
linenumbersfoo: 1 12
linenumbersbar: 1 1
```

The problem seems to be the variable `number`, if I write e.g. `5` instead of `$number`, it works.

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: quick debug: to pass variable, use `-v` option.. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: *This should run in a while loop* - no, it shouldn't, at all

Comment: Please stop changing the requirements. When you do, also indicate what you expect as output.

Answer (score 1):

Since the field `foo` occurs together with the field `bar` it is possible to create a very clear algorithm:

```
awk '/bar/ {A[NR]=0} /foo/ {A[NR]++} END {for(i in A) print i,A[i]}' file
```

```
1 1
5 0
6 0
8 0
12 1
15 1
21 0
```

As we can see, if shift the second column, can get the line numbers for displaying 1 - true and 0 - fals:

```
1 
5 1
6 0
8 0
12 0
15 1
21 1
   0
```

Let's do it:

```
awk '/bar/ {A[NR]=0} /foo/ {A[NR]++} END {for(i in A) {if(A[l]) print i; l = i}}' file
```

```
5
15
21
```

Victory! We will display the first row and bring it to the desired form - format the output:

```
awk '
BEGIN   {printf "linenumbersfoo:"}
/bar/   {A[NR]=0}
/foo/   {A[NR]++; printf FS NR} 
END     {printf "\nlinenumbersbar:"
        for(i in A) {if(A[l]) printf FS i
                l = i}
                print ""
        }
' file
```

```
linenumbersfoo: 1 12 15
linenumbersbar: 5 15 21
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in a shell loop, `awk` will do it for you.

This is an `awk` script that you can store in a script file and invoke with `awk -f script.awk filename` (modified to work with recent edit of the question):

```c
BEGIN {
        follows["foo"] = "bar"
        follows["bar"] = "foo"
}

{
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
                if (lookfor == "") {
                        if ($i in follows)
                                lookfor = follows[$i]
                } else if ($i == lookfor) {
                        record[$i] = (record[$i] == "" ? "" : record[$i] OFS ) FNR
                        lookfor = follows[$i]
                }
}

END {
        for (i in record)
                printf "%s:\t%s\n", i, record[i]
}
```

Running this on your example data:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
foo:    1 12 15
bar:    5 15 21
```

The script sets up a `follows` associative list.  The list says that when `foo` has been found, we need to look for `bar`, and when `bar` has been found, we're interested in finding `foo` again.

The `awk` script looks for the strings in `lookfor`.  Initially, it looks for any of the keys in the `follows` array, and then uses this array to set `lookfor` to the string to look for next.  Each time it finds a string it's looking for, it stores the current line number in the associative array `record` for the corresponding string.

At the end, the collected line numbers in `record` are outputted.

The funky-looking line

```
record[$i] = (record[$i] == "" ? "" : record[$i] OFS ) FNR
```

adds the line number to the end of the string of line numbers in the `record` array. If the string is empty, it just sets it to the current line number, but if it already contains something, a comma is inserted between the existing string and the line number.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: adding an improvement to match your EDIT...

one suggestion with awk:

```
BEGIN {
  ffoo=0; ffoos=""; fbars="";
} 
/foo/ {
  ffoo=1; ffoos=ffoos" "NR;
} 
/bar/ {
  if ((match($0, "foo") == 0) && (ffoo!=0)) {
    fbars=fbars" "NR; 
    ffoo=0;
  }
} 
END {
  print "linenumbersfoo: "ffoos"\n"; 
  print "linenumbersbar: "fbars"\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But now found out my test file isn't really representing my real problem. See EDIT in question. I tried with getline, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have a `grep`- only approach:

```bash
linenumbers(){
    grep -now "$1\|$2" file \
    | grep -Fw -A1 "$1" \
    | grep -Fw "$2" \
    | cut -d: -f1
}
```

Run:

```bash
# search for bars following foo:
$ linenumbers foo bar
5
15
21

# search for foos following bar:
$ linenumbers bar foo
1
12
15
```

Might be, that some options are `GNU grep` only, not sure.

Answer (score -3):

For *foo*:

```
for i in `awk '/foo/{print NR}' filename`; do sed -n "$i,/bar/{;=;p}" filename|sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| awk '/foo|bar/'; done|awk '/bar/{print $1}'|perl -pne "s/\n/ /g"| awk '{print "linenumbersfoo: "$0}'
```

Output:

```
linenumbersfoo: 1 12
```

For *bar*:

```
for i in `awk '/foo/{print NR}' filename`; do sed -n "$i,/bar/{;=;p}" o1|sed "N;s/\n/ /g"| awk '/foo|bar/'; done|awk '/bar/{print $1}'|perl -pne "s/\n/ /g"| awk '{print "linenumbersfoo: "$0}'
```

Output:

```
linenumbersbar: 5 18
```